# all sample vuforia's app showing "unfortunately stopped" in Android

Tags: android, macos, adt, vuforia

I'm trying install latest Vuforia SDK in my Stuff (Mac Os 1.6.8 + ADT-mac-bundle) and follow step by step Instruction. So far is well. In this condition, I use emulator with AVD and setting my emulator with built-in webcam for camera. When I try app in emulator always showing "unfortunately stopped". Any suggestion for this problem?

Note: I still wonder for this issue, if issue about hardware. It's mean I must buy gadget with Android OS. I use emulator because I don't have gadget with Android OS. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia is using the device's GPU to render the texture. So you will need to get your hands on some hardware.